# Emf in ac generator

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I know that emf induced in ac generator equals [N.B.A.w.sin(wt)] And i noticed that the negative sign of lenz rule disappeared. Does this mean that emf will not oppose the change in magnetic flux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know ♀(magnetic flux)=NBACos(wt)
According to faraday's law emf=-d♀/dt
Differentiating it with respect to t we will get emf=NBAwSin(wt)
This does not mean that it violates lenz's rule.But if you study  lenz's rule or faraday's law  carefully you will came to know that emf produced does not opposes magnetic flux but it opposes change in magnetic flux
So in case of ac generator let us assume that Bvector represnts magnetic field and let the armature coil is moving in such a way that the flux through it is decreasing then the emf 's direction (for simplicity use current's direction) will be in such a way that it compensate the decreasing flux by creating a magnetic field in same direction. If flux is increasing through coil then the current will flow in that direction such that it tries to decrase the incresing flux.